# Java String.compareTo - continue to compare even the characters are of different value at first

Tags: java, string

I know there is a method of String which allows me to compare two Strings, which is called compareTo. I was trying to write a modificated version of this method. My issue is that my method stops when a difference between 2 characters was found. For example:

```
public static int stringCompare(String s1, String s2) {
    int i  = 0, n1, n2;
    while(true)  {
        if (s1.length() <= i && s2.length() <= i) {
            return 0;
        } else if (s1.length() <= i) {
            return -s2.charAt(i);
        } else if (s2.length() <= i) {
            return s1.charAt(i);
        } else {
            n1 = s1.charAt(i);
            n2 = s2.charAt(i);
            if (n1 != n2) {
                i++;
                return n1 - n2;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

My main looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "AB";
    String str2 = "AA";
    System.out.print(stringCompare(str1, str2));
}
```

The result of the comparison is 1, because the character 'B' is equal to 66 in the charset and 'A' is equal to 65 -> 66 - 65 = 1. That means the String str1 is greater then str2.

If I change the Strings and add one character more to both of them, the remaining characters after the character index 1, in my case 'A' and 'B', are not going to be compared.

Here is the updated main, which will give me the same result as the previous.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "ABA";
    String str2 = "AAB";
    System.out.print(stringCompare(str1, str2));
}
```

Even the value of both Strings is equal 0 ((65 + 66 + 65) - (65 + 65 + 66)) the result is 1 because the characters at index 2 of the Strings ('A' and 'B') will not be compared.

The instance method of Strings gives me the same result. Even when I use the method str.compareTo(str), the value of the comparison is 1.

Could anyone explain me how can I modify my function, so the other characters will be included in the comparison?

Thank you.

Comment: You may not want to have so many returns, if you don't want to return early.  Is it supposed to compare ASCII values until either string runs out of values to compare?  Writing out specifications ahead of time can help immensely

Comment: what do you want to achive? `str.compareTo(str)` will make a comparision if the `str` values are equal or non equal and grant you a result which of either one is lexographicly greater, but it wont grant you the result of summing up all ascii values for each letter and checking if this sum is equal. If you do want such a function just sum up the ascii values by parsing the `char` to `int` and compare these values in the end.

Comment: You return the difference of character values of the first differing position. Whatever would have come after that must keep the sign of the first difference. Considering that java compareTo returns -1, 0 or 1, what would you want to return instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're returning once you've found a difference

```
if(n1 != n2)
{
    i++;
    return n1 - n2;
}
```

Instead, to keep on computing, you'll want a sum variable

```
int sum = 0; //at the start of the method
[...]
if(n1 != n2)
{
    i++;
    sum += n1 - n2;
}
[...]
return sum; //at the end of the method
```

This can be done a bit cleaner

```
int stringCompare(String a, String b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length() && i < b.length(); i++)
        sum += a.charAt(i) - b.charAt(i);
    return sum;
}
```

If all characters are taken into account, you can either loop over the excess after

```
int stringCompare(String a, String b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length() && i < b.length(); i++)
        sum += a.charAt(i) - b.charAt(i);
    for(int i = b.length(); i < a.length(); i++)
        sum += a.charAt(i);
    for(int i = a.length(); i < b.length(); i++)
        sum -= b.charAt(i);
    return sum;
}
```

Or sum and subtract

```
int stringCompare(String a, String b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        sum += a.charAt(i);
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
        sum -= b.charAt(i);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

iterate through the characters in the strings. 
where they don't match, store the difference. 
return the total difference at the end.